unknown reference swagger issue when issuing buf generate with stream rpc
I am trying to generate swagger.json using buf generate.
Here is my sample proto file
import "google/rpc/status.proto";

  rpc Create(stream CreateRequest) returns (stream
    CreateResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post : "/v1/create"
      body : "*"
    };
  }

Here is my sample buf.yaml. I have added the googleapis dep
version: v1beta1
name: buf.build/github/repo
deps:
  - buf.build/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
  - buf.build/razorpay/googleapis-pubsub
  - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
build:
  roots:
    - proto

the swagger file that is generated is
    "/v1/create": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "result": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/x.y.v1.CreateResponse"
                },
                "error": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/google.rpc.Status"
                }
              },
              "title": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "body",
            "description": " (streaming inputs)",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/x.y.v1.CreateRequest"
            }
          }
        ],
        "tags": [
          "x"
        ]
      }
    },

Due to nature of stream, the "error" block is getting auto-generated and swagger is throwing the below error
Unknown reference:
#/definitions/google.rpc.Status:[line-number]:[column-length]

How to fix this?

See Generate implicit refrerences

@DazWilkin this helped. Thanks

Thanks to Daz for the reference,
Solved the issue by generating deps using buf and then generating swagger
So basically, i was doing this before
buf mod update && buf generate
Doing the following solved the issue
buf mod update && buf generate buf.build/googleapis/googleapis && buf generate
